# how to check which date comes first in a year on comparing two dates using php

Tags: php, javascript, date

I have to find which date comes first in a year comparing two dates.
  For Example i want to display the date which comes first in year. FirstDate=2/3/2011 and SecondDate=1/1/2011
   I should get the answer as 1/1/2011  how to compare the two dates

Comment: Please be specific, if you need to compare the dates using the `PHP` or `javascript`. Because, In this question, I do not see anything related to javascript except the `javascript` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare date with [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function

```
$date1=strtotime('2/3/2011');
$date2=strtotime('1/1/2011');

if ($date1 < $date2)
{
   echo '2/3/2011 come first';
}
else
{
   echo '1/1/2011 come first';
}
```

But be aware of 2038 bug

> Unix timestamps cannot deal with dates
>   before Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC
>   and after Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07
>   UTC

Comment: Instead of strtotime() you may also use mktime().

Comment: @Udo true, but why would anyone want to use mktime for anything? It's so awkward to use, especially in this case, where you had to split the date first.

Comment: @Udo G, `mktime()` would need separate parameters unlike `strtotime()`

Comment: Thank you can you please give tips for this question in javascript

Comment: @akila how about you use the search function instead of asking people things that have been answered many times before.

Comment: @akila: look at here if you need this in javascript as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-2-dates-with-javascript

Comment: @Starx: right. I don't see where the question states that he wants to use strings.

Comment: @Udo G, `FirstDate=2/3/2011` is his question symbolizes that he is intending to use `2/3/2011` as string more than as a separate paramters. But Of course, I could be wrong, but in either case, use of `strtotime()` is far better.

Comment: @Gordon: For me he only asks how to compare dates without specifying in what format the date is. Should he have year, month, day as separate integers then `mktime()` is certainly better than constructing a string. Also, strtotime() does a lot of guessing work which is a potential source for bugs (things like a year being interpreted as hour+minute and such, see the PHP manual page). Anyway, he should know that there is more than one solution.

Comment: @Udo how about giving it as an answer then ;)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use Date :

```
var d1 = new Date(2011, 2, 2);
var d2 = new Date(2011, 0, 1);
if (d1 > d2) {
    alert('Date 1 is greater than Date 2');
}
...
```